# shorter way to execute a function named as $_POST value

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_POST['fn'])) {
    if ($_POST['fn'] == 'giveme_lb') {giveme_lb();}
    elseif ($_POST['fn'] == 'giveme_lc') {giveme_lc();}
    elseif ($_POST['fn'] == 'ico_save') {ico_save();}
    ...
}
```

So I need to execute a function with the name of `$_POST['fn']` value.

Any shorter way to say this?

something like `$_POST['fn']();`

Comment: Wait.. this approach seems to be very bad and dangerous... rather decide on the given output which method to  call using some logics

Comment: That's a really bad idea. You wouldn't want to execute `"phpinfo"`, for instance. Stick to the if/else or rewrite as switch/case.

Comment: @Peter, I think that a malicious function can be executed regardless of the way saying `$_POST['fn']();` or with `if else` or `switch` construction.

Comment: @puerto, the if clauses implement a whitelist, so there is no possibility for arbitrary code execution in the code as shown in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call_user_func($_POST['fn']);
```

See http://php.net/call_user_func.

But in fact `$_POST['fn']()` will work in all non-ancient PHP versions as well (5.3+ if I remember correctly).

But you absolutely need to *whitelist* the value first, so users can't invoke arbitrary code on your system:

```
$allowed = ['giveme_lb', ...];
if (!in_array($_POST['fn'], $allowed)) {
    throw new Exception("Not allowed to execute $_POST[fn]");
}
```

Comment: Actually, yes, it should.